# Gatsby Image Not Found

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, gatsby-image

So I am messing around with creating a markdown blog and for some reason I cannot get images to work.

#### Gatsby-config.js

```js
plugins: [
    'gatsby-plugin-image',
    'gatsby-plugin-sharp',
    'gatsby-transformer-sharp',
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-filesystem',
      options: {
        name: 'images',
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images/`,
      },
      __key: 'images',
    },
]
```

Images are stored in `src/images`

#### blogpost.md

```
---
title: New Provider
image: ../images/new-provider.jpg
imageMeta:
  attribution:
  attributionLink:
featured: false
---
```

Here is how I am querying the data

```js
export const query = graphql`
  query PostsByID($slug: String!) {
    mdx(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      body
      frontmatter {
        title
        authors
        date
        featured
        image
        tags
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

And here is my `img` element

```
<Img alt={title} fluid={image} key={title} />

// I tried this too
<img alt={title} src={image} />
```

When the page loads , I just see my alt text and in the console I see `http://localhost:8000/images/new-provider.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To query an image, you need the `childImageSharp` data (fetched from Gatsby's sharps and transformers, you have them both installed).

If the data structure and paths are properly set, your GraphQL query should look like:

```
export const query = graphql`
  query PostsByID($slug: String!) {
    mdx(slug: { eq: $slug }) {
      body
      frontmatter {
        title
        authors
        date
        featured
        image {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid(width: 125, height: 125) {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
        tags
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

There you have the proper nodes and properties that Gatsby image have to render your image. Then you can use:

```
<Img alt={title} fluid={image.childImageSharp.fluid} key={title} />
```

If your GraphQL query is not able to fetch `childImageSharp` node (test it in the GraphiQL playground at `localhost:8000/___graphql`) check the relativity of the markdown paths.

Comment: Field "image" must not have a selection since type "String" has no subfields. Is what I get when I updated to this

Comment: This issue I had is that one of my markdown files has 'image: ''` which was breaking things